# Change title with JS with button in secondary page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've two pages in HTML-PHP:

first page, the main page, has buttons that can rederict to second page, second page has title and image that I would like to change with JS code.
I try to use function in my first page to change title in second page but it doesn't work.

My FIRST PAGE:

```
<div class="hover">
<a onclick="hello();" href="secondPage.php" target="_blanck" ;>Second Page</a>
</div>
```

My SECOND PAGE:

```
<h2 id="title2">Hy</h2>';
```

MY JS:

```
function hello (){
document.getElementById("title2").innerHTML='<h2 id="title2">Hello!</h2>';  
}
```

I'm new in JS and I think there's something wrong in my JS code, can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: `I try to use function in my first page to change title in second page but it doesn't work.`...that is because your two pages never exist in the browser at the same time. The second page replaces the first one when you click the link. Therefore code from page 1 cannot change anything in page 2 because page 2 doesn't exist yet when page 1 is loaded. Please make sure you understand the basics of how websites work. If you want to do something on your second page, then the JavaScript for doing that must also be on the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following codes to do it.

**firstPage.php**

```
<div class="hover">
    <a href="secondPage.php?change=1" target="_blank" ;>Second Page</a>
</div>
```

**secondPage.php**

```
<h2 id="title2">Hy</h2>
<?php
if ( (isset($_GET['change'])) AND ($_GET['change'] == 1) )
{
    ?>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("title2").innerHTML='<h2 id="title2">Hello!</h2>';
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```